# Form field async validation not performing HTTP call

Tags: angular, validation, angular7

I'm creating an Angular+NodeJS+SQlite app. On one of my views i need to introduce an IP in a reactive form. That IP should be unique in the database so I'm using an async validator to check every time a character is introduced in the input if that value is in the DB.

Following angular documentation and some videos I've managed to assemble this code:

Definition of the form control:

```
createForm() {
    this._addNodoForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        name: [this.nodo.name,[Validators.required]],
        ip: [this.nodo.ip,[Validators.required, uniqueIPValidator(this._nodeService)]],
        status: [this.nodo.status, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(1)]],
        vbus_ip: [this.nodo.vbus_ip, [Validators.required]],
        physical_address: [this.nodo.physical_address, [Validators.required]],
        tunnel_address: [this.nodo.tunnel_address, [Validators.required]],
        transfer_rate: [this.nodo.transfer_rate, [Validators.required, Validators.max(9600), Validators.min(0)]],
    });

}
```

Definition of the validation class:

```
export function uniqueIPValidator(nodeService: NodeService): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    if(c.value!=''){
        return nodeService.getUniqueIp(c.value).pipe(map(
          (addresses :any)=> {
            return (addresses && addresses > 0) ? {"uniqueIP": true} : null;
          }));
    }
  }
}

  @Directive({

    selector: '[uniqueIP]',
    providers: [{ provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting: UniqueIpValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
  })


  @Injectable()
  export class UniqueIpValidatorDirective implements AsyncValidator{
    constructor(private nodeService: NodeService) { }
    validate(ctrl: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
      return uniqueIPValidator(this.nodeService)(ctrl);
    }
  }
```

nodeService.getUniqueIp(): This method returns a the http response consisting in the ips that match the control value. The method works perfectly using `.subscribe()`

```
 getUniqueIp(ip:string):Observable<any>{
        return this._http.get(this.url + 'unique-ip/' + ip);
    }
```

And finally the html code of the input:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="ip" class="form-control" uniqueIP>
<div *ngIf="_addNodoForm.get('ip').errors?.uniqueIP">IP must be unique</div>
```

The problem is that the HTTP call is not even performed using `.pipe(map(` it does not reach the API rest method that retrieves the ips from the DB. I've tried using a subscription system and it does actually retrieve the ips but i dont think thats how it is supposed to return the `Observable<ValidationsErrors>` so its not showing the error on the form either.

```
export function uniqueIPValidator(nodeService: NodeService): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    if(c.value!=''){//to avoid making the http call when the input is empty
        return nodeService.getUniqueIp(c.value).pipe().
          subscribe(addresses => {
            console.log('DIR: '+addresses);
            if(addresses!=null){
              return {"uniqueIP": true};
            }
          },error=>{
            console.log(error);
          });
    }
  }
}
```

I know from theory that Async validators are only fired when the sync validators return null but i dont really know what that means in this case, could that be a problem?
This is just for educational porpuses as I'm trying to understand async validators so i can use them in the future. Any suggestions about the problem or the post itself are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the signature for `FormControl` in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) you will see that it's 
constructor parameters are:

```
formState: any = null, 
validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | AbstractControlOptions | ValidatorFn[], 
asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[]
```

I separated the parameters onto their own individual lines to emphasize that there are three of them.

I believe your issue may be that you are mixing in your `uniqueIPValidator AsyncValidatorFn` with the synchronous `Validators.required ValidatorFn`.

Try changing:

`ip: [this.nodo.ip,[Validators.required, uniqueIPValidator(this._nodeService)]],`

to

`ip: [this.nodo.ip, Validators.required, uniqueIPValidator(this._nodeService)],`

By doing this you will be providing the `uniqueIPValidator(this._nodeService)` parameter as the **third** parameter (the one for async validators) instead of inside of the array of the **second** parameter.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! Guess i have to read again the form docs.

Comment: You are very welcome! I am glad it solved your problem. It was a very easy mistake to make to be honest :)